# Failed google maps in android application

Tags: android, maps

I tried using google maps in my android application but the maps failed.The grid appears blank. Can anyone help with this ? thank you

Comment: is the google logo appearing? and if you can please post the logcat..check in the logcat for error contacting google servers..if such an error is there it is because you have an invalid key for maps.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to use internet to load the map ? because I'm trying to make it work with the AVD emulator

Comment: of course man..you should have internet connection in your pc..if map doesn't appear then check my answer below.